# Python 3 control flow in script with lots of steps

Tags: python, syntax, control-flow

I'm writing an algo in Python (learning it just to write this algo) and I'm breaking it into small chunks or modules so it's understandable.

In Python, is there a clean way to run through a set of functions with the last passing in the value of the previous?

I have this now, but there will be probably a dozen more steps making this look like a massive pyramid and fo:

```
calculate_excess_returns(
    calculate_returns(
        get_monthly_historical_returns('./assets/monthly_historical_returns.csv')
    )
)
```

I could also do this but I find it way less readable:

```
monthly_historical_returns = get_monthly_historical_returns('./assets/monthly_historical_returns.csv')
calculated_returns = calculate_returns(monthly_historical_returns)
calculated_excess_returns = calculate_excess_returns(calculated_returns)
```

In JavaScript we have a common control flow called "promises" that look like this:

```
getJSON('story.json')
  .then(function(story) {
    return getJSON(story.chapterUrls[0]);
  }).then(function(chapter1) {
    console.log("Got chapter 1!", chapter1);
  });
```

You can see that's passing the results as they come and it's easy to follow the flow: getJSON of story *then* getJSON of first chapter *then* tell user they got to chapter 1.

It'd be nice in my algo script to be able to do something similar like:

```
   SomeModuleOrPackage
    .startWith(get_monthly_historical_returns('./assets/monthly_historical_returns.csv'))
    .then(calculate_returns)
    .then(calculate_excess_returns)
```

Just something that's very clear what each step is. Maybe some sort of array of the functions that loops and somehow passes the value to the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want a nicer looking way to compose functions. I'd recommend you use some functional programming package, such as `funcy` or `fn`. Here is an example utilising the first package.

```
import funcy


pipeline = funcy.rcompose(
    get_monthly_historical_returns,
    calculate_returns,
    calculate_excess_returns
)

result = pipeline('./assets/monthly_historical_returns.csv')
```

Or if you don't plan to use the pipeline several times, you can calculate the result straight away:

```
result = funcy.rcompose(
    get_monthly_historical_returns,
    calculate_returns,
    calculate_excess_returns
)('./assets/monthly_historical_returns.csv')
```

The functions are executed from left to right. The output of one function is passed as the first argument to the next one.You can use `functools.partial` from the standard library to provide additional agruments to your functions, if they require more than one argument, e.g.

```
import funcy
from functools import partial 


composition = funcy.rcompose(
    partial(func1, additional_arg_name=something),
    ...
)
```

I think you get the idea. Regarding your `getJSON` example, you can pass anonymous functions (`lambda`) to `rcompose` for the code to look almost identical to your JavaScript example.

You can install the package via pip: `pip install funcy`

Answer (score 1):

You could put them into a `list` or `tuple` and loop through them:

```
var = './assets/monthly_historical_returns.csv'
for func in (get_monthly_historical_returns,
             calculate_returns,
             calculate_excess_returns):
    var = func(var)
```